# Entity Framework Core: Owned type that has navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have some classes:

```
public class Project 
{
     public TimeLine TimeLine { get; set; };
}

public class TimeLine 
{
     public ICollection<TimeLinePhases> TimeLinePhases { get; set; };
}

public TimeLinePhase 
{
}
```

The class `Project` owns `TimeLine` and this all works fine until I specify the navigation between `TimeLine` and `TimeLinePhase`.

Fluent API code that specifies `TimeLine` is owned:

```
  builder.Owned<TimeLine>();
  builder.entity<Project>().OwnsOne(p => p.TimeLine);
```

I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'TimeLine.TimeLinePhase' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

So then I specify the relation between `TimeLine` and `TimeLinePhase` like this:

```
builder
        .Entity<TimeLine>()
        .HasMany(t => t.TimeLinePhase)
        .WithOne()
        .IsRequired(false);
```

But now I get this error:

> The entity type 'TimeLine' cannot be configured as non-owned because it has already been configured as a owned. Use the nested builder in `OwnsOne` or `OwnsMany` on the owner entity type builder to further configure this type

How can I have `TimeLine` as an owned type, and still have the relation between `TimeLine` and `TimeLinePhases`?

Comment: I'm curious as I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Owned types can only contain other owned types as collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I brief search revealed an answer. It seems configuring an owned type having a collection is not allowed. The problem being an owned type cannot act as a principal entity for the collection

See comments by AjVickers at this GitHub page: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27175

It seems a redesigned datastructure is needed.

Comment: It means that `TimeLinePhase` should also be an owned type. I don't know it that's feasible. The best solution is probably to map `TimeLine` as a 1:1 association with `Project`.